# How can you repeat a number x times in a column in a continuation, in excel

Tags: excel, rows

I want to do a list like -> 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3..., but in a column in excel. What would be the formula to do that automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Try in **A1**:

```
=ROUNDUP(ROW()/4,0)
```

and copy downward

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with code, let's say you wanted to do this in column A starting in row 1:

```
x = 1 'the starting row value
y = 1 'the starting column value
z = 12 'the number of entries you ultimately want to make
entryEnd = 4 'the number of entries per value
entryStart = 1 'the start of the entries
a = 0 'the starting number of the list of values

Do While x<=z
entryStart = 1 'reset the value of entryStart    
a = a + 1
    Do While entryStart <= entryEnd
    cells(x, y) = a
    x= x + 1
    entryStart = entryStart + 1
    Loop
Loop
```